# discord.js - Send image on member ban?

Tags: discord.js

Hi so I would like my bot to send an image in the general chat when someone gets banned by for example, dyno, but I do not know how to do that, if anyone could help, I would appreciate it!

Comment: Do you have code from (failed) attempts? If yes, please share it :)

Answer (score 3):

You'd create a listener for `guildBanAdd`, and send a message to the particular channel when a user is banned.

```js
client.on('guildBanAdd', (guild, user) => {
    if(guild.id === 'GuildID') {
        const notificationChannel = guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === 'general');
        notificationChannel.send('Message', {files: ['image address/url']});
    }
});
```